# What do we know about the rate of convergence of the mean of RVs with infinite variance?

Tags: variance, convergence, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers, fat-tails

What, if anything, do we know about the rate of convergence of of the mean of identically distributed, independent or stationary random variables drawn from a distribution with a finite mean and infinite or nonexistent variance?

I have asked a separate question about the conditions under which the mean of such variables do converge. In answering this question, you may assume that such conditions, whatever they are, hold.

Comment: Can you please link to your other question.

Comment: I can't help much but there's probably some version of a WLLN that doesn't require finite variance. So, if you can find that WLLN, the proof of it will probably answer your question.  I don't know or I would give you a name but there are so many that I bet one of them relaxes the finite variance assumption.